# 301 redirect of old .cfm website to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

Hopefully someone can help.

Ive been trying to redirect some old .cfm pages from our old website as I can see that they have a large number of back links and would like to redirect them to our new wordpress site.

Only problem is every time i try any kind of 301 redirect all i get is a railo error rather than the redirect.

http://www.miltonkeynestreesurgery.co.uk/about.cfm

Ive included the link above to the error and hopefully someone can help.

I also don't have access to the old .cfm pages as they were deleted by the web designer (which I'm sure was a screw up on his part.)

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you have tried?

Comment: Hi, yes I've tried, RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product-detail.cfm$ / [L,R=301] and Redirect 301 /oldpage.html http://www.yoursite.com/newpage.html. i've tried different variations of these as well but nothing seems to resolve the issue.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried using WordPress itself to do the redirect for you? I typically just use [Simple 301 Redirects](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/) and the native WordPress rewrite rules should handle the 301 redirect.

Comment: Thanks Jared, yer I've tried that and I know it works well because I've used it previously but sadly it still doesn't seem to do the .cfm redirect for me, some one said its because railo and php don't work well together so its one or the other but then others have told me they are ok so I'm a bit more than just stuck at the moment and frustrated. thanks for your help